# R splits up text columns when importing SPSS files

Tags: r, string, text-mining, spss

I'm using the memisc package to read in an SPSS file with `spss.system.file("filename.sav")`. One of the columns has a lot of text and is split up into a total of nine columns with a maximum of 255 characters each.

I would like R not to split up the column. How can I do this?

Comment: is the column text split in the spss file or you're saying R is splitting the text?

Comment: R is splitting it up, it's just one column in the spss

Comment: I would try to *rio* package in R. It's kind of a swiss army knife for data import-export. It uses different packages to import files. Try it with that and see if the same thing occurs.  It uses a different package for importing spss files.